# Setting up Web Root for LAMP and never worry about it again

Tags: lamp, development, www

I made a fresh install of Ubuntu in my laptop. I just installed the LAMP stack and phpmyadmin.

I tested them with `http://localhost` and `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` and they're working fine.

Now I've made a lot of research, and my little experience with ubuntu for web development has been a headache.

Knowing that this is a fresh install. Is there a way I can set permissions so it's like in windows, where you don't have to worry about anything, just copy paste your app, develop, you and the app can create, delete, modify files, folders?

Is there a way I can develop without spending hours with the console to figure out how can I allow my web application to upload files or delete files properly?

If there is a way that also applies security good practices, it's fine, although I don't mind security, this is just my laptop to develop web apps and it's only accessed by me.

Thank you, remember that I'm relatively noob with Ubuntu and I haven't understood completely it's users/groups/permissions system.

**EDIT:** I know where to put the PHP Files, I just want to set permissions and forget.

Comment: To never worry again about a root server, disable networking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a long description in the joomla Docs. This may help you to find out what is missing.

https://docs.joomla.org/Configuring_a_LAMPP_server_for_PHP_development/Linux_desktop

Comment: Ok, that article you sent me helped me a lot and made me realize there's no such "set permissions and forget". If you copy elements from other folders to your app folder inside /www/html/, you'll have to go to the console and re-set the permissions so those files can be deleted or modified by your app. A headache for someone used to WAMP in Windows :P